# Finetuing BERT with masking and having multiple correct labels

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I aim to fine-tune a BERT model for a specific task involving simple arithmetic operations like "5 + 3 = 8" or "7 plus 2 equals 9". My dataset comprises thousands of examples where one operand, operator, or result is masked. For instance:

- Masked: "1 added to [MASK] equals 7", Label: "1 added to 6 is equal
  to 7"
- Masked: "6 plus 5 [MASK] 11", Label: "6 plus 5 gives 11"

The challenge lies in ensuring that multiple correct labels are accepted for a masked sample during training. For instance, if the model predicts "equals" instead of the masked token in the second sample, it should be considered correct.

Answer (score 0):

I recently fine-tuned a model to recognize if a sentence was inside the context i choose, and in doing so, preparing a well-structured dataset made it all.
You could cross-use another model that accepts all the answers you wish after using the one you're fine tuning to get the masked word.

Dataset Sample:
...
1 added to 6 is equal to 7, True
1 added to 6 gives 7, True
1 added to 6 greater than 7, False
...

Hope I've at least given you a hint for a better idea!